# How to pass on the content of a HttpInputStream and send it to another Rest Api in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, inputstream

I have a REST API Web Service that acts as middleware that redirects calls onto another REST API Service.

For example in this case I upload a file on the webpage. And this Web Service receives the files and sends them to another API that actually processes the files.

It is something like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExecuteFileUpload()
{
    IHttpActionResult res;
    try
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var requestedFiles = new List<System.IO.Stream>();
        var url = "http://localhost:2288" + "/api/v1/templates/upload";
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = httpRequest.Files;
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[index];
                    var fileName = postedFile.FileName;
                    var fileInMemory = postedFile.InputStream;
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(fileInMemory), "f" + index, fileName);
                    index++;
                }
                res = await ForwardPost(url, content);
            }
        }
        else
            res = BadRequest();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        res = InternalServerError(ex);
    }
    return res;
}
```

The forward post function is simple just like this:

```
protected async Task<IHttpActionResult> ForwardPost(string url, MultipartFormDataContent forwardContent)
{
    IHttpActionResult res;
    using (var client = CreateClient())
    {
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, forwardContent))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JToken>();
                res = Ok(content);
            }
            else
            {
                res = InternalServerError();
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

As you can see I just want to forward whatever is passed to me from the webpage and forward it to the actual REST API that handles this.

However it throws an exception on this line:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(url, forwardContent)
```

It throws a System.IO.IOException

> Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.

Why is this the case?
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try copying the postedFile.InputStream to a new memory stream before adding it to your new MultipartFormDataContent.

Comment: I tried to do that. However it resulted in the content I sent through became 0 byte files. I ended up doing something like: read it to a byte array and loaded it back into a memory stream.
However I really puzzled by the error message. Because in no instance I am trying to close the stream. I am hoping I can just pass the stream along.
This way especially when I am trying to upload a bigger sized file it would not soak up memory.

Comment: true, it will soak up some memory on your system. There may be a way to handle the request object more directly such that you can dispose your second request after completing the first one. Instead of directly in the ForwardPost method

Answer (score 1):

The using in the ForwardPost function will dispose the forwardedContent from the calling method. This dispose will attempt to dispose the "postedFile.InputStream" reference from the request object of the origin method. This is likely deeply tied to the httprequest object.

```
using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, forwardContent))
```

The solution is to copy the postedFile.InputStream to a new memorystream such that it can be disposed separately.